# Catogerizing by year in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a program of photoalbums in simple PHP, but i want to make it a little more advanced then i used to do.

Usually i wrote it like this:

```
<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT year FROM photo");
while($record = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
echo $record->year."<br>";
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT albumName, url FROM photo WHERE year = '".$year."'");
while($album = mysql_fetch_object($query2)){
echo "<a href=\"".$album->url."\">".$albumName."</a><br>";
}
} ?>
```

As you would understand it's really bad to have two while loops in one, so i want to do it differently. I want to learn how to do this better. The thing is, I don't know a name for this so it's difficult to search on this subject. Is there anyone able to hand me a snippet of code, a source or something to get me on the way?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
<?php 
  $year = ''; // create a generic variable that will hold the album year
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT albumName, url, year FROM photo ORDER BY year"); // Sort by year
  while($album = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
      if($album->year != $year){ // check if $album->year is the same as the $year value
        echo $album->year."<br>";  // if not the same echo the year
      }
      $year = $album->year;  // set the $year value to the $album->year
      echo "<a href=\"".$album->url."\">".$album->albumName."</a><br>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this:

```
<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT albumName, url, year FROM photo");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
       echo $record->year."<br>";
       echo "<a href=\"".$record->url."\">".$albumName."</a><br>";
    }    
 ?>
```

What would be wrong? 
Now your code might produce an album more than one times, if there are many albums per year.

Comment: If i would do it like this, it'll mean it will show the year of the album after before every album name. The thing is: currently there are only two years filled with more than 10 albums per year. Sean's answer did the job but thank you for your help!